# If A and B are disjoint finite sets, use induction on $|B|$ to show that $|A \cup B|$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked "If A and B are disjoint finite sets, use induction on $|B|$ to show that $|A \cup B|$ is finite. "

The main reason I'm having difficulty with this is that it seems so obvious I don't know how much detail they want me to go into. They give me a big hint with using induction on $|B|$ though so I'll start there.

I want to say that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$ but they ask me to prove this later on in the question so I think it's something they don't want me to assume.

If $|A| = n$ and $|B| = 1 \Rightarrow |A \cup B| = n+1$ which is finite. Therefore true for $|B| = 1$ This seems obvious using Venn diagrams but I can't think of a way to do this step algebraically without assuming that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$

Assume true for $|B| = k$

i.e. $|A \cup B| = x = $ finite

Prove true for $|B| = k + 1$

Assuming $A$ stays the same size and as $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, this implies that $|A \cup B| = x+1 =$ finite. Again, I'm assuming that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$

Therefore if true for $|B| = k$ true for $|B| = k+1$. Since true for $|B| = 1$ true for $|B| \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

If I carried out the same induction but saying $|A|$ instead of $|B|$ I'd get the same results so it's also true for $|A| \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

I feel this isn't rigorous enough and I don't think I should be using $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$ but I'm not too sure how to tackle this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Which definition of finite do you use? Existence of bijection with an element of $\omega$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry but the question doesn't specify for some reason.

Comment: If the hint suggests you to use induction, we may assume that the relevant def of *finite* is bijection with some $n \in \omega$, where $n = \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1 \}$.

Comment: If so, the base step is something like : we have $|B|=1$; this means : $B = \{ b_0 \}$. So, $A \cup B = A \cup \{ b_0 \}$ where $b_0 \notin A$ by disjoinctness of $A,B$. Thus, if we have a bijection from $A$ to $n$, this means that  $A = \{ a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_{n-1} \}$ and it is enough to "extend" the bijection to $n+1$ with $a_n' = b_0$. This seems to me enough to prove that $A'=A \cup B$, for $|B|=1$, is bijectable with a finite $k$, so is *finite*.